# Where is the "On My Computer" folder on my Mac, and where is local folder for emails?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2011

I just installed Outlook 2011 on my Mac, and I like the look and feel, but find it hard to get around the basics, so I have a couple questions.

Where is the "On My Computer" folder or file on my local drive?

When saving emails on my computer, where exactly do they go?

Comment: The "On My Mac" folder only appears if you have a local account as well as an Exchange account. If you only have Exchange, it won't show. As for where the emails go, that depends on how you save them.

Comment: As for where mails go: in case you're still in doubt wether to use Outlook or Mail.app: Apple's Mail is Time Machine-aware. When you want to restore a message in Mail: just activate Mail, and while Mail is active open Time Machine. You'll see the Time Machine star field, but for Mail rather than for Finder. No need to *know* where messages are stored when using Mail and Time Machine. Plus: it uses a small file for each message, which works great with Time Machine (as opposed to the single huge `outlook.pst` that Outlook uses to store *all* messages).

Answer (score 2):

Try `~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity/` -- for Office 2008 that's where it kept local files.